# Insert data from table A into table B with different column names, using a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql

Tried to use a cursor to cut and input data from table A into table B, but keep returning a syntax error. This is for a school project, much appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_activedata_sap_pp1()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
DECLARE TARGET_CURSOR record;

begin
    SET search_path TO "public";
    FOR TARGET_CURSOR IN
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            "public".t_activedata_sap_pp1
    LOOP
        declare
        month_get int2 := replace(TARGET_CURSOR.cpudt, SUBSTR(TARGET_CURSOR.cupdt, 5, 2));
        date_get varchar := replace(cpudt, TARGET_CURSOR.cpudt, SUBSTR(TARGET_CURSOR.cpudt, 1,6));
        tcode_get varchar := "40";
    
        begin
            insert into "public".t_activedata_sap_pp1("year", "month", plant, "date", tcode, "number", "content", department, typemove, costcenter, costcenter_2, value, workplace, workplace_code)
            values(TARGET_CURSOR.mjahr, TARGET_CURSOR.month_get, TARGET_CURSOR.werks, TARGET_CURSOR.date_get, TARGET_CURSOR.tcode_get, TARGET_CURSOR.matnr, TARGET_CURSOR.mat_text, '', TARGET_CURSOR.bwart, '', '', TARGET_CURSOR.menge2, '', '')
        end;
    END LOOP;
END;

$procedure$
;
```

Comment: You can't have a DECLARE block inside a LOOP block. Just declare all variables in the "main" DECLARE block that you already have. And string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes, `"40"` is an identifier, `'40'` would be a string constant. But why the LOOP at all? A simple `insert into ... select ...` seems enough here.

Comment: I don't know PGSQL syntax specifics, but looks like you are selecting data and inserting it into same table (`"public".t_activedata_sap_pp1`)? Another comment - why are you using cursor? Set based operations are usually much more efficient.

Comment: Most of the function body is just nonsense. Use a plain `INSERT` statement instead.